# How to display UISearchBar results non-dynamically?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uisearchbar

Hey guys I have this piece of code for a UISearchBar that searches dynamically. But since the DataSource is a VERY large NSArray the search process has an annoying lag that I need/must/have to get rid of.

The problem is that I could not find a way to do the search in a non-dynamically way like the user would type the search string and only after hitting the Search button on the keyboard is when the search process would being and present the result.

My code is as follows:

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {

if (searchText.length == 0) {
    isFiltered = NO;
} else {
    isFiltered = YES;
    filteredCodigos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (NSDictionary *item in values) {
        NSString *strSymbol = [item objectForKey:@"symbol"];
        NSString *strName = [item objectForKey:@"name"];
        NSRange strRangeSymbol = [strSymbol rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        NSRange strRangeName = [strName rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

        if ((strRangeSymbol.location != NSNotFound) || (strRangeName.location != NSNotFound)) {
            [filteredCodigos addObject:item];

        }
    }

}

[_tableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `searchBarSearchButtonClicked:` search bar delegate method to trigger the search instead of `searchBar:textDidChange:`.

You can also, if using `searchBar:textDidChange:`, require that the length of the search string is at least 2 or 3 characters long before performing a search.

You should probably also consider changing your data source so, rather than using an array, you're using Core Data (or similar). Both so you don't need everything in memory at once and so you can run efficient searches.

Comment: I'll try both first and second suggestions, but the using Core Data I already tried and the results were not that different, as I said, the NSArray has 90k NSDictionaries item and each item has 10 entries.

Comment: after evaluating the two options, that one that worked better for my project is the first one. Thank you for input.